# Can non View class become a FirstResponder?

Tags: ios, objective-c, motionevent, shake, uiresponder

I have a custom class (MyEventHandler) which has nothing to do with the UI in my app. I would like it to be able to catch a MotionShake event. As I understand I need to make MyEventHandler a first responder for that.

Here's what I've done.
I inherited `MyEventHandler` from `UIResponder` and implemented `canBecomeFirstResponder` method. However when I call `becomeFirstResponder` it returns 0, so does the `[self isFirstResponder]`.

I checked the current first responder and it turned out to be `nil`.

If I do the same things with my ViewController it works fine, so my question is: is it even possible to make a custom class, which doesn't inherit from UIView, a first responder?

Here's the code that I have:

```
@interface MyEventHandler : UIResponder
  - (void)start;
@end

@implementation MyEventHandler
- (void)start {
      [self becomeFirstResponder];
  }

- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {
      return YES;
  }
- (void)motionEnded:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
      if (motion == UIEventSubtypeMotionShake) {
          NSLog(@"Shake-shake-shake!");
      }
  }

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you call `becomeFirstResponder` on a View object that is not on view hierarchy, it will return nil.

For your purpose, you can make use of notifications to tell your custom class(`MyEventHandler`) when you recieve the motion event on your ViewController

Comment: I'm trying to build a Framework that can be embedded in any application, so I can't modify the app's ViewControllers.

As for the `becomeFirstResponder` I call it in `MyEventHandler` class, not in a View. And `MyEventHandler` only inherits from `UIResponder`.

Comment: @oranJess I'm doing this exact thing now, did you figure it out?